# How can I query mongo to find arrays that contain TWO elements from another array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have the following documents in mongo:

```
{_id: 0, tags: ['first', 'second', 'third', fourth']},
{_id: 1, tags: ['fifth', 'seventh', 'first', second']},
{_id: 2, tags: ['eigth', 'awesometh', 'fancyth']},
{_id: 3, tags: ['fourth', 'fifteenth', 'something']},
```

I want to find documents which contain TWO OR MORE from the following array: `['first', 'second', third', 'fourth', 'fifteenth']`

The only idea I have so far is to generate I giant query with a clause for each combination, like so:

```
{$or: [
    {tags: {$in: ['first', 'second']}},
    {tags: {$in: ['second', 'third']}},
    {tags: {$in: ['first', 'third']}},
    ...etc...
  ]
}
```

This is obviously not an elegant solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an `aggregate` pipeline that uses [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection) to find the matched `tags`, and then [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) to count them:

```
var tags = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifteenth'];
db.test.aggregate([
    // Project the original doc along with a count of the tag matches
    {$project: {
        _id: 0,
        matches: {$size: {$setIntersection: ['$tags', tags]}},
        doc: '$$ROOT'
    }},
    // Filter to just those docs with at least 2 matches
    {$match: {matches: {$gte: 2}}}
])
```

Output

```
{ "matches": 4, "doc": { "_id": 0, "tags": ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"] }}
{ "matches": 2, "doc": { "_id": 1, "tags": ["fifth", "seventh", "first", "second"] }}
{ "matches": 2, "doc": { "_id": 3, "tags": ["fourth", "fifteenth", "something"] }}
```

Comment: Wow awesome! I had never heard of $setIntersection